# iOS Swit 3 - filter array inside filter

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, arraylist, swift3

I would like to filter array inside a filter. First I have a big array of Staff object (self.bookingSettings.staffs). Inside this array I have multiple object like this :

```
"staffs": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Brian",
        "services": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "pos": 1
    },...
```

I would like to filter this array in order to have only services with `id = 3`.

I succeed to have if first object is equal to `3` with this code :

```
self.bookingSettings.staffs.filter({ $0.services.first?.id == self.bookingService.id })
```

but that takes only the first item.

I think I have to filter inside my filter function, something like this to loop over all object inside services :

```
self.bookingSettings.staffs.filter({ $0.services.filter({ $0.id == self.bookingService.id }) })
```

but I've the following error: `Cannot convert value of type [BookingService] to closure result type Bool.`

Is this a good idea ? How can I achieve this ?

Comment: `self.bookingSettings.staffs.filter({ !($0.services.filter({ $0.id == self.bookingService.id }).isEmpty })`? In other words `anyArray...filter(HereYouNeedsToReturnABoolToKnowIfYouKeepTheObjectOrNot)`. So `![...].isEmpty` may do the trick, because you want to keep the ones where it's there is more than 1 objects corresponding in the subarray.

Comment: @Larme `!a.filter{ ... }.isEmpty` should be avoided, in favor of `contains(where:)`

Comment: Good point @Alexander. Since I'm not a Swift developer, using `contains(where:)` wasn't my first choice, but I was more attracted on explaining the reason of the compiler error "Cannot convert value of type [BookingService] to closure result type Bool".

Comment: @Larme Ah yes, I suppose I should have addressed that prior to providing my alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use `filter`, which would look something like this:

```
self.bookingSettings.staffs.filter {
    !$0.services.filter{ $0.id == self.bookingService.id }.isEmpty
}
```

This code is constructing an entire array of filtered results, only to check if its empty and immediately discard it. Since filter returns *all* items that match the predicate from the list, it won't stop after it finds a match (which is really what you're looking for). So even if the first element out of a list of a million elements matches, it'll still go on to check 999,999 more elements. If the other 999,999 elements also match, then they will *all* be copied into `filter`'s result. That's silly, and can use way more CPU and RAM than necessary in this case.

You just need `contains(where:)`:

```
self.bookingSettings.staffs.filter {
    $0.services.contains(where: { $0.id == self.bookingService.id })
}
```

`contains(where:)` short-circuits, meaning that it won't keep checking elements after a match is found. It stops and returns true as soon as find a match. It also doesn't both copying matching elements into a new list.